# compare two dates time hours and minutes (not secs)?

Tags: c#

This is may be silly question. But I am missing logic here. I have to compare dates with date time with hours and minutes (not with seconds).

IF first field time is older then second field execute condition

right now I am doing `if (Convert.ToDateTime(newItem["Modified"]) <     Convert.ToDateTime(properties.ListItem["Modified"]))`

example `if("02/12/2015 11:58" < "02/12/2015 12:01")` then execute condition.

Comment: So would `02/12/2015 11:58:42` = `02/12/2015 11:58:15`?

Comment: What problem(s) are you having with the code that you currently have?

Answer (score 6):

You could create new `DateTime` objects with mostly the same values, but with seconds set to 0. Example:

```
DateTime date1WithoutSeconds = new DateTime(dt1.Year, dt1.Month, dt1.Day, dt1.Hour, dt1.Minute, 0);
DateTime date2WithoutSeconds = new DateTime(dt2.Year, dt2.Month, dt2.Day, dt2.Hour, dt2.Minute, 0);

bool b = date1WithoutSeconds < date2WithoutSeconds;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could subtract the two dates, and if the TotalSeconds of the difference is less than 60 AND the minues are the same, then they are equal:

```
var first = Convert.ToDateTime(newItem["Modified"]);
var second = Convert.ToDateTime(properties.ListItem["Modified"]);

if (first.Subtract(second).TotalSeconds < 60 && first.Minute == second.Minute)
{
    Console.WriteLine("They are equal");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One more way that should work.

```
DateTime date1 = Convert.ToDateTime(newItem["Modified"]);
DateTime date2 = Convert.ToDateTime(properties.ListItem["Modified"]));

if( date1.AddSeconds(-date1.Second) < date2.AddSeconds(-date2.Second) ) {

}
```

But, I would wonder...is it really that you need to ignore the seconds and "floor" the result so that 12:59:00 is the same as 12:59:59 but different than 12:58:59 even though there's only a second of difference...or do you need to know that it's greater than a minute of difference?  If you really just want to make sure that it is a minute apart, use TimeSpan `(date1 - date2).TotalSeconds > 60`

I doubt this is likely, but if your DateTime is a string WITH milliseconds, then do:

```
if( date1.AddSeconds(-date1.Second).AddMilliseconds(-date1.Millisecond) <
    date2.AddSeconds(-date2.Second).AddMilliseconds(-date2.Millisecond) ) 
{

}
```

Comment: I was also wondering that. But I interpreted the question as 'ignore seconds', so that `1:00:59 < 1:01:01`

Comment: @RufusL, yeah, sometimes people aren't sure what they really need, so I like to throw out extra crap and see what happens :-P

Comment: Really should truncate the milliseconds as well, just in case.

Comment: @juharr, since both appear to be coming from strings, I think it's very unlikely that the strings have milliseconds...but I went ahead and added it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the DateTime.CompareTo method.

Grab and assign both dates as DateTime objects:

```
DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(newItem["Modified"]);
DateTime compareDate = Convert.ToDateTime(properties.ListItem["Modified"]);
```

You can now use the CompareTo method of the DateTime object to see if the instance is earlier, the same, or later than the other, returning -1, 0, and 1 respectively.

So, following your example: if("02/12/2015 11:58" < "02/12/2015 12:01"), first date being date and second being compareDate, the code:

```
date.CompareTo(compareDate);
```

will return -1, telling you the instance invoking the method is earlier than the object you are comparing it to.

Here is [the MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ata5aya(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: The OP is asking how to get rid of the "seconds" in the time, not the right way to compare.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, the sample data you've mentioned in your question doesn't include seconds, so by default `Convert.ToDateTime` will assign '00' as seconds, so it *would* compare without the seconds.
But let's say that you do provide seconds in the actual data. You can use the following:

```
var date1 = Convert.ToDateTime(newItem["Modified"]);
var date2 = Convert.ToDateTime(properties.ListItem["Modified"]);
if (date1.AddSeconds(-date1.Second) < date2.AddSeconds(-date2.Second))
```

Comment: `date1.AddSeconds(-date1.Second)` - and what if the dates have milliseconds?

Comment: Not part of the OP's requirements

Comment: We're not here to fulfill requirement, we're here to help people build great software components. By not thinking ahead of what OP is asking, you're not doing anyone a favor.

Comment: @CodeCaster: With all due respect. Great software should solve a real-life problem. i agree some people create awesome software for research and for just the fun of it, but most software is created for the sake of answering a need. In this case, though there could be several edge-case scenarios, like you've mentioned above, the OP may no care on the impact of msecs and/or the data may never have msecs (see sample data provided by OP). In any case, I'll take the vote-down as a lesson learned

Comment: My point is that the web in general and this site in specific is already full of code snippets that serve a very specific purpose, ignoring any edge cases or being incomplete simply because the asker didn't realize they were forgetting a detail. Working with dates isn't trivial, and I have linked four Q&As that do exactly what OP wants, where those edge cases and workarounds are discussed. Please don't take offense, but I don't think your code does what OP wants, and you're only partially to blame because OP didn't ask a complete question.